# Flow errors with react component

Tags: reactjs, redux, flowtype

I have just started a new application with react and this time am using Flow.

I'm having some problems with reported errors that I don't think are errors. Here is my class with the problems:

https://pastebin.com/x7AHi8ZB

```
'use strict';
// @flow

import {HashRouter, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
import React from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import axios from 'axios';
import Loader from './loader/Loader';
import Sidebar from './sidebar/Sidebar';
import Header from './header/Header';
import * as appActions from '../actions/appActions';



  type Props = {
    dispatch:  Function,
    loadingTxt:  string,
    errorTxt:  string,
    loading:  bool,
    error:    bool
  };


/**
* App Component.
*/
class App extends React.Component<Props> {
  constructor(props: Props) {
    super(props: Props);

    this.data = {};
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get(window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host + '/data/app.json')
      .then((response: object) => {
        this.data = response.data
        setTimeout(() => this.props.dispatch(appActions.appHasLoaded(): Function), 2000);

      }).catch(() => {
        this.props.dispatch(appActions.appHasErrored(): Function);
      });
  }

  render(): React.Element {
    if (this.props.error || this.props.loading) {
      return (
        <div className={this.props.error ? 'app-loader is--error' : 'app-loader'}>
          <Loader size="app" />
          <p className="app-loader__text">{this.props.error ? this.props.errorTxt : this.props.loadingTxt}</p>
        </div>
      )

    } else {
      return (
        <div className="app-inner">
          <HashRouter>
            <Route>
              <Header {...this.data.header} />
            </Route>
          </HashRouter>

          <div className="page">
            <HashRouter>
              <Switch>
                <Route path='/'>
                  <Sidebar {...this.data.sidebar} />
                </Route>
                <Route>
                  <p>Not Found</p>
                </Route>
              </Switch>
            </HashRouter>
          </div>
        </div>
      )
    }
  }
};

const mapStateToProps = (state: object) => {
  return {
    loading:  state.app.loading,
    error:    state.app.error
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App);
```

And these are the errors:

---

```
>'dispatch' is missing in props validation    
  src/js/components/App.js:37:37
          setTimeout(() => this.props.dispatch(appActions.appHasLoaded(): Function), 2000); 'error' is missing in props validation       
  src/js/components/App.js:44:20
      if (this.props.error || this.props.loading) {
                      'loading' is missing in props validation     
  src/js/components/App.js:44:40
      if (this.props.error || this.props.loading) {
                                     'errorTxt' is missing in props validation    
  src/js/components/App.js:48:74
            <p className="app-loader__text">{this.props.error ? this.props.errorTxt : this.props.loadingTxt}</p> 'loadingTxt' is missing in props validation  src/js/components/App.js:48:96
            <p className="app-loader__text">{this.props.error ? this.props.errorTxt : this.props.loadingTxt}</p>
```

---

What I don't understand is why it is reporting them as errors, I have my props defined. Am I suppossed to also use type hinting everytime I use a prop in a render method? That it is going to make the code real hard to read!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you go to the Flow documentation [HERE](https://flow.org/en/docs/react/components/) you can read that

> We import React as a namespace here with import * as React from
>   'react' instead of as a default with import React from 'react'. When
>   importing React as an ES module you may use either style, but
>   importing as a namespace gives you access to React’s utility types.

It means that your solution with generics can work if you import React like `import * as React from 'react'` (not `import React from 'react'`).
If you wish to keep your current import statement for react then add `props: Props` at the top of your class and remove `Props` generic from the class declaration like this:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  props: Props
  // rest of the code
```

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it! Is this documented anywhere? All I seemed to find was using the <Props> syntax

Comment: @riscos3 I've updated my answer. If this answers your question please mark it as correct. Thanks :)